# Why isn't a semi-colon inserted after this assignment of an object literal?

Tags: javascript, syntax

Take this Javascript code:

```js
foobar = {}
["one", "two"].forEach(item => {
  console.log(item)
})
```

If you run this code in the browser or in Node, you get this error:

```
hi.js:2
["one", "two"].forEach(item => {
               ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined
```

However, if you add a semi-colon manually at the end of the first line `foobar = {};`, you no longer get this error, instead you get the expected output of `one` and `two`.

I know Javascript has automatic semi-colon insertion, and I know that many people recommend to always use semi-colons in order to avoid issues like this. My question is specifically about this case: why wasn't a semi-colon automatically inserted at the end of the first line? An object literal, followed by an array literal, isn't valid Javascript syntax, is it? Let me see:

```js
foobar = {} ["one", "two"];
console.log(foobar);
```

This actually prints `undefined` without throwing an error! I did not expect that!

So I guess my real question is: why is an object literal, followed by an array literal, in an assignment, considered a syntactically correct Javascript line, and what is it doing?

Comment: Square brackets are used for property access as well as array literals. I guess you could say there's an inherent ambiguity there and this is how the interpreter deals with it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In parser view, when you are not adding a `;`, the parser will be looking at it as:

```
{}["one", "two"]
```

An empty object's index, which is not available. So it technically is a Reference Error, as it doesn't exist or `undefined`. So effectively, this gets interpreted as:

```
undefined.forEach(...)
```

Answer (score 5):

The parser thinks you mean:

```
foobar.two // foobar['two'] = foobar.two
```

In Action:

```
foobar = {one:1,two:2}
["one", "two"] // returns 2
```

Think of it like this:

```
obj = {};
obj.foo = 1;
obj['foo']; // equals 1
obj;['foo']; // equals obj {foo:1}, ['foo']
```